# Is it possible to have pandas csv_reader "sep" parameter use space a word and a number?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv, separator

I'm using pandas (python) csv_reader, and I don't know if it is possible or efficient to have a regex expression on the "sep" parameter that returns the dataframe as I want.

I'm reading from a single columns csv that I have to convert into a 11 columns csv.

I'm trying to have a separator that achieves:

1. Uses long spaces as separator;
2. Uses spaces between a word and a string containing numbers (999-BBB CCCC);
3. Uses spaces between a string containing numbers and a word (AAA 999-BBB).

The data comes in this format (multiple rows):

```
111-XXX XX XXXX           AAA 999-BBB CCCC            0,00                  01/01/1950     111.111        22. DDDD        11.111,11       11.111,11
```

So far I have only achieved separating large spaces and spaces with a dot with: sep=r"[ .]{2,}"

I need the data to become like this:

```
111-XXX XX XXXX | AAA | 999-BBB| CCCC | 0,00 | 01/01/1950 | 111.111 | 22 | DDDD | 11.111,11 | 11.111,11
```

Trying to detect space followed by a number (to split AAA from 999-BBB) with "[ ][0-9]" ends up deleting the first numbers as well (resulting in 99-BBB) which is not desirable.

This is my code so far:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("myarchive.csv",
                 sep=r"[ .]{2,}",
                 engine="python",
                 names = col,
                 usecols = col,
                 na_filter=False,
                 keep_default_na=False)
```

Comment: Can you try `sep='\s\s+` or just `sep='\s+`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `delim_whitespace=True` paremeter.
From the docs:

> delim_whitespace : bool, default False
>
> Specifies whether or not whitespace (e.g. ' ' or '    ') will be used as the sep. Equivalent to setting sep='\s+'. If this option is set to True, nothing should be passed in for the delimiter parameter.

And then manually fix the first field.

Edit: You could also use `read_fwf` if the format is always the same:

```
widths = [
    15,  # 111-XXX XX XXXX
    14,  # AAA
    8,   # 999-BBB
    16,  # CCCC
    16,  # 0,00
    17,  # 01/01/1950
    16,  # 111.111
    7,   # 22.
    5,   # DDDD
    17,  # 11.111,11
    16,  # 11.111,11
]
df = pd.read_fwf('test.csv', widths=widths, header=None)
print(df.values)
```

Comment: Guess I should have clarified: the data in each row is not the same, so setting a width is not going to help.  It is nice to know about read_fwf though! It can be useful in other tasks.